# Doctrine rename all my index even if i don't ask for it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

i'm new to doctrine and Symfony, and i don't uderstand why my migration always contains some line for renaming index.

I prefere keeping a readable semantic name for my index, what option should i use ?

This is the command i use for creating migration:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

This is my entity :

```
/**
 * ArticleFournisseur
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article_fournisseur")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ArticleFournisseur
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Qte", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $qte;

    /**
     * @var float|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Prix_unitaire", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $prixUnitaire;

    /**
     * @var \Article
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Article")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="no_article", referencedColumnName="no_article")
     */
    private $NoArticle;

    /**
     * @var \Emplacement
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Emplacement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Id_emplacement", referencedColumnName="Id_emplacement")
     */
    private $idEmplacement;

    /**
     * @var \Fournisseur
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Fournisseur")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Id_fournisseur", referencedColumnName="Id_fournisseur")
     */
    private $idFournisseur;

    /**
     * @var \Statut
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Statut")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Id_statut", referencedColumnName="Id_Statut")
     */
    private $idStatut;
}
```

This is part of the result i get in the migration file generated :

```
// ./migrations/Version202007211565895.php
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article_fournisseur RENAME INDEX fk_art_fou__art TO IDX_AC1DA055BC2E22B2');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article_fournisseur RENAME INDEX fk_art_fou__emplacement TO IDX_AC1DA05515B9D0D9');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article_fournisseur RENAME INDEX fk_art_fou__fou TO IDX_AC1DA055E3E87F1D');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article_fournisseur RENAME INDEX fk_art_fou__statut TO IDX_AC1DA05541A2C7F1');
```

I just did one thing that is special, i create my entity from my database, by using the following command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

Thank you for your help

**Edit :**

Ok, now the line which was renaming index have disapears, but i still got the same problem with name of the foreign key.
Please could you take a look at this :

```
// ./migrations/Version2020072194047.php

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article_fournisseur DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_art_fou__statut');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article_fournisseur ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AC1DA055BC2E22B2 FOREIGN KEY (no_article) REFERENCES article (no_article)');
```

See, the foreign key constraint is drop, then it's re-create with another name.

But maybe i must have to create an other question for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine allows naming indexes (see the [docs](http://%3C?php%20/**%20%20*%20@Entity%20%20*%20@Table(name=%22ecommerce_products%22,indexes=%7B@Index(name=%22search_idx%22,%20columns=%7B%22name%22,%20%22email%22%7D)%7D)%20%20*/%20class%20ECommerceProduct%20%7B%20%7D)).

For example:

```
/**
 * ArticleFournisseur
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article_fournisseur",indexes={@Index(name="idx_idEmplacement", columns={"idEmplacement"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

You can adapt this as needed.